# Is it possible to import a .css file using ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am trying to import a .css file using ES6 modules but I am getting an error. Is it even possible to import a css file without using a bundler or a transpiler (like webpack)?

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a
>   non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/css"

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            {{ msg }}
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script type="module">
            import './style.css'

            new Vue({
              el: '#app',
              data: {
                msg: 'Hello World!'
              }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to import a non-script into another script.

Comment: It doesn’t make sure, you will indeed need a bundled like webpack

Comment: May be you can use **alternative style sheets** => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Alternative_style_sheets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it with ES6 modules. You *can* dynamically import it into the HTML though:

```
<script>
    const url = "./style.css";
    document.head.innerHTML += `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=${url}>`;
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect! It gets the job done (even though it's an ugly way of doing it)

Comment: For me, this reloaded the entire CSS files present in the file, making it look a bit ugly for some time. Append worked the best for me.

Comment: @Liga so is it perfect or ugly? :)