# Right way to use node modules with Firebase hosted project

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, openlayers, firebase-hosting

I want to host a web app on Google Firebase hosting, and `import` code from node modules, but I can't find the right way to go about this.

I have installed the modules on my dev machine into the main directory of the Firebase install, and imported them from my own JS file, but any way I try, I get error messages. For example (`ol` stands for OpenLayers):

```
import '../ol/ol.css';
import {Map, View} from '../ol';
import TileLayer from '../ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from '../ol/source/OSM';
```

I then get these errors:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/css".

The MIME type in that error message is sometimes also `"text/html"`.

Are there more steps than just placing `package.json` and `node_modules` in the right place?

I've tried tinkering around but am probably missing something obvious...

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here.  Firebase Hosting just serves static content.  It doesn't host a node app or run JavaScript code on the backend.  You can write code for Cloud Functions and proxy Hosting to it, but that's a completely different thing than what you're doing here.

Comment: Ok, I am using npm to install modules that I want to run in the Browser, I am using FB hosting to serve up the pages with these modules...

Comment: The use of Firebase Hosting isn't really relevant here, since it just serves static code.  It will work the same way that any hosting services delivers static content.  It sounds like you're just having problems building that static content.

Answer (score 1):

If that JS code is from a node file, you can't import a .css file there.

Check also [Is it possible to import a .css file using ES6 modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56510754/is-it-possible-to-import-a-css-file-using-es6-modules)

Comment: I see. Other errors, from loading from other import statements remain though.

Comment: import may not be support depending on your setup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54384073/import-not-working-on-node-js-version-11-8-0

Comment: try with require instead of import

Comment: Hmm, I am using the newest version of Chrome and npm... I'm not sure how to translate those lines into require unfortunately as I am importing individual classes?